# System.InvalidCastException Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My program is very simple, two view controllers, one button that, when pressed, proceeds to the next view controller. It worked at first, but when I now try to execute it I receive:

> System.InvalidCastException: < Timeout exceeded getting exception details >

This is the code telling the button to switch view controller:

```
partial void Knapp1_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        UIStoryboard storyboard = this.Storyboard;
        ViewControllerTwo ViewController = (ViewControllerTwo)
            storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ViewControllerTwo");

        this.PresentViewController(ViewController, false, null);
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

The error message pops up beside these two lines of code:

```
ViewControllerTwo ViewController = (ViewControllerTwo)
            storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ViewControllerTwo");
```

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: Check that the view controller in that storyboard is actually using the `ViewControllerTwo` as not just its string-based "Id", but also its custom class in the UI designer.